# Html Rowspan but with border around cell/row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am looking to see whether it is possible to highlight a row with border even if there is a rowspan set? For example in this mock up UI we have some rowspans for columns C and D, but i need to be able highlight a single row as in the cyan one in the below screenshot i.e. row 4. to highlight this row as the current selected row. I have produced sample Html to show basic outline of the rowspanned columns, however i am not sure how to go highlighting the entire row that overlays a rowspanned row?

[image]

```css
.main-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.main-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #282C31;
}

.main-table td {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">15/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">47</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">1A</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="8">1A</td>
      <td>780</td>
      <td>1056</td>
      <td>276</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lastPeriodOfTheDay">
      <td style="text-align: center;">15/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">48</td>
      <td>418</td>
      <td>761</td>
      <td>343</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td>167</td>
      <td>548</td>
      <td>381</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
      <td>313</td>
      <td>438</td>
      <td>125</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">1B</td>
      <td>-314</td>
      <td>159</td>
      <td>473</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
      <td>602</td>
      <td>837</td>
      <td>235</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
      <td>231</td>
      <td>533</td>
      <td>302</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">6</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>388</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">7</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">2A</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="8">2A</td>
      <td>92</td>
      <td>315</td>
      <td>223</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">8</td>
      <td>772</td>
      <td>882</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">9</td>
      <td>720</td>
      <td>979</td>
      <td>259</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gasDayEndPeriod">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
      <td>188</td>
      <td>561</td>
      <td>373</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">2B</td>
      <td>665</td>
      <td>990</td>
      <td>325</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">12</td>
      <td>442</td>
      <td>716</td>
      <td>274</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have created a basic version of the HTML here https://jsfiddle.net/j61sr9zh/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. I don't know if it's possible to cross the rowspan cells either. Maybe someone else knows if it's possible.

You'll have to be able to select the row somehow; I just arbitrarily picked the first row.

```css
.main-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.main-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #282C31;
}

.main-table td {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

tr:first-of-type td:not([rowspan]) {
  border-top: 2px solid cyan;
  border-bottom: 2px solid cyan;     
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td style="text-align: center;">15/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">47</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">1A</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="8">1A</td>
      <td>780</td>
      <td>1056</td>
      <td>276</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>725</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lastPeriodOfTheDay">
      <td style="text-align: center;">15/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">48</td>
      <td>418</td>
      <td>761</td>
      <td>343</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>474</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>287</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td>167</td>
      <td>548</td>
      <td>381</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>546</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
      <td>313</td>
      <td>438</td>
      <td>125</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">1B</td>
      <td>-314</td>
      <td>159</td>
      <td>473</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>109</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
      <td>602</td>
      <td>837</td>
      <td>235</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>581</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>256</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
      <td>231</td>
      <td>533</td>
      <td>302</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>179</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">6</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>435</td>
      <td>388</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>291</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>144</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">7</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">2A</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="8">2A</td>
      <td>92</td>
      <td>315</td>
      <td>223</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>312</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">8</td>
      <td>772</td>
      <td>882</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>739</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>143</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">9</td>
      <td>720</td>
      <td>979</td>
      <td>259</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>715</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>264</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gasDayEndPeriod">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
      <td>188</td>
      <td>561</td>
      <td>373</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>541</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4">2B</td>
      <td>665</td>
      <td>990</td>
      <td>325</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>674</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>316</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">16/06/2021</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">12</td>
      <td>442</td>
      <td>716</td>
      <td>274</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>701</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```